# Running PHP 5.4 and PHP 7 on the same server

Tags: php, laravel, centos, plesk, php-7

The company I work for has a legacy PHP app running on PHP 5.4.16. Today I thought I would try to upgrade it to PHP 7.0.9 for the performance benefits among other things. This is the version I personally use and have no issues with it.

Anyway, before I updated the CentOS 7 server with it, I figured I would try updating it through Plesk 12.5. Didn't work so well, a number of errors came up that I think are related to the libraries the app uses not being compatible with PHP7. Switched is back to PHP 5.4.16 so the app keeps working. (Note they never really setup a test environment and changes were just made to the production files... yep). Due to all this, I am very hesitant to update PHP in CentOS and set the environmental paths to PHP 7.

Well I want to rebuild the web app using Laravel 5.3 and PHP 7, but certainly don't want to disrupt the current system, so I am trying to figure out how I can have a separate install of PHP 7 to use for the Laravel web app.

Where can I specify the php.ini file to use for the Laravel web app such that it uses PHP 7?

Comment: PHP 5.4 has been end-of-life for a year now and is dangerously insecure to run as a result. http://php.net/eol.php Doing this with Plesk is likely to be very difficult - it's notoriously difficult to do anything custom in. Consider a second server while you transition to PHP7.

Comment: Have you ever considered docker for easily control your environment ?

Comment: @ceejayoz PHP 5.4.16 on CentOS/RHEL is not insecure as it receives backports.  These enterprise linux distributions only support one version of PHP per release but keep them updated for security fixes.

Comment: You wouldn't just be able to specify a different php.ini.  You'd need to run PHP7 separately.  This isn't too complex, if you're a sysadmin.  However, it depends how you have PHP configured.  You said you're using Plesk so that may limit your options for compatibility.  Normally, with fastcgi, you just run a new PHP process under a different socket/port and specify that socket/port in your web server config under that virtualhost.

Comment: Try to contact Plesk support, I heard it's free now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plesk 12.5 provides multiple PHP versions on one server.

- Let the live version run with php 5.x
- Create a new subscription with PHP 7 (changeable under PHP-Settings in the client interface)
- Start developing there with PHP 7

[see linked screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lcz1m.png)